# Validation for from in recatjs is not happenig?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have tried making the username and possword field validated but it by default setting "username is incorrect" when the page loads but it should happen only after user types and then the error should be shown respectively. So once user enters the username and if length is less than "3" a message should be display below the respective fild "Username should be 3 digit!!!"

```
import withRoot from './modules/withRoot';
// --- Post bootstrap -----
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import history from './history';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import { FormGroup, FormControl, ControlLabel } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Field } from 'react-final-form';
import Typography from './modules/components/Typography';
import AppFooter from './modules/views/AppFooter';
import AppAppBar from './modules/views/AppAppBar';
import Axios from 'axios';
import AppForm from './modules/views/AppForm';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { Alert } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { email, required } from './modules/form/validation';
import RFTextField from './modules/form/RFTextField';
import FormButton from './modules/form/FormButton';
import FormFeedback from './modules/form/FormFeedback';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Home from './Home';
import Dashb from './Dashb';
import Admin from './Admin';



const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  form: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(6),
  },
  button: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(3),
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  feedback: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
  },
}));

const SignIn = (props) => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [usernameerror, setUsernameerror] = useState("");
  const [passworderror, setPassworderror] = useState("");
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(true);
  const classes = useStyles();
  let demo;
  function validateForm() {
    if(username.length!=3)
    {
      return("Wrong username");
    }
    if(password.length!=6 )
    {
      return("Wrong password")
    }
    return 1;
    
  }

  function setIncorrect() {
    setStatus(false);
  }



  function setCorrect() {
    setStatus(true);
  }

 function validate(){
   let usernameerror ="";
   let passworderror = "";

   if(username.length==3){
     usernameerror = 'invalid username';
   }

   if (usernameerror){
     setUsernameerror({usernameerror});
     return false;
   }
 }

 


  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    let user =  Axios.get(
      'http://localhost:9000/admin-service/admin/check/' +
        username +
        '/' +
        password
    )
      .then(response => {
        demo = response.data
        if (demo == true) {
          props.history.push({
            pathname: '/admin',
            username
          });
          console.log('####')
          
        } else{
          console.log('not true')
          Functions();
      }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error.response.data)
        setIncorrect()
      })
  };

  function Functions() {
    alert("PLEASE ENTER CORRECT CREDENTIALS!!!!!!!!!!")
}

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <AppAppBar />
      <AppForm>
        <React.Fragment>
          <Typography variant="h3" gutterBottom marked="center" align="center">
            Admin Sign In
          </Typography>
        </React.Fragment>

        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className={classes.form} noValidate>
          <TextField
            variant="outlined"
            margin="normal"
            required
            fullWidth
            id="username"
            label="Admin-Id"
            name="username"
            autoFocus
            onChange={e => { setUsername(e.target.value); setCorrect() }}
          />
          
          <div style={{ fontSize: 11, color: "red"}}>
            {validateForm()}
            </div>
         
          <TextField
            variant="outlined"
            margin="normal"
            required
            fullWidth
            name="password"
            label="Password"
            type="password"
            id="password"
            autoComplete="current-password"
            onChange={e => { setPassword(e.target.value); setCorrect() }}
          />
          <div style={{ fontSize: 11, color: "red"}}>
            {validateForm()}
            </div>
          {(!status) && <Alert severity="error">Incorrect credentials. Please try again</Alert>}

          <FormButton
            type="submit"
            className={classes.button}
            //disabled={!validateForm()}
            size="large"
            color="secondary"
            fullWidth
          >
            Sign In
              </FormButton>
        </form>
        


        <Typography align="center">
          <Link underline="always" href="/premium-themes/onepirate/forgot-password/">
            Forgot password?
          </Link>
          <p>NOTE-PASSWORD IS YOUR USER PIN</p>
        </Typography>
      </AppForm>

    </React.Fragment>


  );
}

export default SignIn;
```

Comment: You can use Formik and Yup package for validation. Which is really great. Take a look for example - https://webomnizz.com/working-with-react-formik-and-yup/

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your validate form function.The conditions were not working in this respective form

```
function validateForm() {
        if(username.length===0)
        {
          return null
        }
        else if(password.length===0 )
        {
          return null
        }
        else if(username.length<3)
        {
          return("Username must be 3 chars long");
        }
        else if(password.length<6 )
        {
          return("Password must be 6 chars long")
        }
      }
```